Is there a name for this type of "2nd order" convergence?
A bit of background on what I'm doing. I'm working on a spreadsheet that calculates lateral deflections of wood frame buildings (how much a building sways to the side during an earthquake or wind event).
In it, we have to start with an assumed fundamental period (Ta) of the building, which can be recalculated with an approximate method until the assumed and re calculated fundamental periods match. This process always converges. For example, starting with an assumed Ta of 0.8 converges to a Ta of 1.48 (single data point).
The thing is, different initial Ta's do not converge to the same Ta. I've filled in a few more data points on the previous image. (more data points filled in). For example, starting at 0.7 converges to 1.9, but starting at 1.7 converges to 0.8. There seems to be a point that converges to itself though (1 roughly converges to 1).
I was expecting all initial Ta values to converge to the same final Ta value like  this.
Is there a name for this? I was thinking something along the lines of 2nd order (non-)convergence, but searching for that didn't get the results I was looking for.

You need to supply some more information about the process involved here. "2nd order" doesn't sound right for the kind of phenomenon you are seeing, it sounds more like you have a process that has many different equilibria (like placing a marble on a corrugated surface).

What kind of process is used to compute the fundamental Ta? If it is iterative, what is each step? It seems strange, especially for a model of physics, that there would be so many convergence points, and that none of them except $1$ would be stable.

Update:
Turns out there as an error in the spreadsheet. All initial Ta's for a given set of properties tested so far converge to the same Ta. I previously suspected the initial unexpected behaviors may have been cause by non-linear stiffness effects and crudeness of some of the approximations, but it turns out that is not the case.

As for the process, its roughly goes like this.
-Start with an assumed Ta
-Distribute forces to each storey based on building code equations
-calculate the storey deflections (movements) based on plywood shear, nail slippage, wall bending, and tie down slippage
-recalculate Ta with Rayleighs quotient
-recalculate the above with the new Ta
-iterate until convergence

So in this case, everything worked out. But is there a name for when initial values converge, but do not converge to the same final value?
